# Covering trigger handler lines for all trigger context use cases

Tags: unit-test

I have written test class but i am not able to cover the specific lines. My apex code is

```
/**
 * RA, 11/25/2016
 */
public class LeadHandler implements TriggerInterface { 

    Map<Id, Lead> newMap;
    Map<Id, Lead> oldMap;

    // used for transferring purchases from leads to contacts
    List<Purchase__c> lstPurchase;

    // initialize generic collections
    public LeadHandler() {
        newMap = (Map<Id, Lead>)Trigger.newMap;
        oldMap = (Map<Id, Lead>)Trigger.oldMap;

        lstPurchase = new List<Purchase__c>();
    }

    public void bulkAfter(){
        if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
            // logic to transfer purchase from lead to contact on conversion
            Set<Id> setConvertedLeadIds = new Set<Id>();
            for (Lead newLead: newMap.values()){
              Lead oldLead = oldMap.get(newLead.id);
              if (newLead.IsConverted  && !oldLead.IsConverted) {
                 setConvertedLeadIds.add(newLead.id);
              }
            }

            if( setConvertedLeadIds.size() > 0 ) {
                lstPurchase = [select Id, Lead__c, Student__c 
                    from Purchase__c where lead__c in :setConvertedLeadIds];  

                for (Purchase__c purchase: lstPurchase) {
                    if ( setConvertedLeadIds.contains(purchase.Lead__c ) ) {
                        purchase.Student__c = newMap.get(purchase.Lead__c).ConvertedContactId;       
                    }
                }
           }
        }
    }

    public void bulkBefore(){

    }

    public void beforeInsert(SObject so){}
    public void beforeUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject so){}
    public void beforeDelete(SObject so){}
    public void afterInsert(SObject so){}
    public void afterUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject so){}
    public void afterDelete(SObject so){}
    public void afterUndelete(SObject so){} 

    public void andFinally() {   
        System.debug(lstPurchase);
        if(lstPurchase.Size()>0){                           
            update lstPurchase;
        }
    }
}
```

These lines are not covered. please help

```
public void beforeInsert(SObject so){}
public void beforeUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject so){}
public void beforeDelete(SObject so){}
public void afterInsert(SObject so){}
public void afterUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject so){}
public void afterDelete(SObject so){}
```

My test class is

```
/*
*    TestClass for : LeadHandler
*/


@istest 
public class LeadHandlertest{


    public static testmethod void testleadhandler(){
        // Testdata for lead object
        Lead testLead = new Lead();
        testLead.FirstName = 'Test First';
        testLead.LastName = 'Test Last';
        testLead.Company = 'Test Company';
        testLead.Status = 'New';
        testLead.Convert_Lead__c = false;
        testLead.Auto_Follow__c = true;

        insert testLead;

        Purchase__c objP = new Purchase__c(Lead__c=testLead.id,Active__c=true,X_of_Remaining_Sessions__c=20);

        insert objP;

        //objP.Active__c=false;

        //update  objP;

        // convert lead
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(testLead.id);
        lc.setOwnerId(UserInfo.getUserId());

        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
        System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());

    }


}

public void afterUndelete(SObject so){}
```

Comment: You need to call these methods from testclass.

Comment: I have tried with but getting error TriggerInterface  l1=new  LeadHandler ();
         l1.beforeInsert();

Comment: `beforeInsert` method expecting sObject parameter. So you need to pass your created record.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger handler pattern you selected requires testmethods to deal with all trigger contexts - before/after insert, before/after update, before/after delete

Since your trigger handler (which looks like the Tidy trigger pattern) really only cares about `after update`, you might consider switching to a different trigger pattern - specifically, the [Separation of Concerns pattern for the Domain layer as used in SFDC Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/apex_patterns_sl/apex_patterns_sl_soc). The domain layer implementation extends `fflib_SObjectDomain` and you only need implement (and hence test) those trigger contexts that are relevant to your application.  This pattern also has some other superior characteristics to the Tidy pattern - notably better recursion control, a true domain layer rather than a trigger handler, and part of a larger design pattern - Separation of Concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this within your test method.

```
LeadHandler l1 = new LeadHandler(); 
l1.beforeInsert(testLead); 
l1.beforeUpdate(testLead, testLead);
l1.beforeDelete(testLead);
l1.afterInsert(testLead);
l1.afterUpdate(testLead, testLead);
l1.afterDelete(testLead);
```

Comment: TriggerInterface l1=new LeadHandler (); 
        l1.beforeInsert(objP);
       
        TriggerInterface l2=new LeadHandler (); 
        l2.beforeDelete(objP);
       
        TriggerInterface l3=new LeadHandler (); 
        l3.AfterDelete(objP);

Comment: i have tried with this. Is this fine?

Comment: Dis this cover your code?

Comment: @Sidharth you don't need to initialise multiple `TriggerInterface` variables. You can invoke all the method using one variable itself. So try to avoid multiple declarations.